# How can I implement a scrollbar for <pre>

Tags: html, css, overflow, code-snippets, pre

I have a `<pre>` tag in my HTML and it bugs when I change the resolution and the output looks:

[image]

It happens when a line gets a little bit longer so that I want to implement a scrollbar to fix this unreadability somehow. I have checked the `overflow` but nothing changed!

Comment: Use `overflow: scroll;` on `pre`

Comment: doesn't change anything.

Comment: well we're going to need your full HTML and CSS. Screenshots make it impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Here is my [pastebin example page](https://codehub.pythonanywhere.com/snippet/e7a44b92b4/). I made you a new snippet with a long comment line in Python. You can easily check the styles there. The `pre` part is bugged!